# My website does not resolve initially. Resolves after few attempts

Tags: asp.net, dns, web, resolve

Enlightened with the knowledge at stackoverflow, I have created an e-commerce website that is hosted on shared hosting from reseller club. The site is built on ASP.NET.

The problem I noticed quite a number of times is that the website does not resolve at first attempt (Page Not Found). After refreshing 3-4 times, it starts resolving and then continues to resolve without any issues. It happens when I try to open it the first time during a given day. Once opened, it works fine for entire day. If this is happening at visitors end also, it will be a huge turn down as no visitor will care to refresh 3-4 times and in turn it means all the money spent on Facebook and Google advertising is wasted.

Can you please suggest how I can **implement a check that the site is up and running all times**?

Also, how can I **verify if this is happening everywhere and not just at my end**?

Many thanks in advance for your help/suggestions.

Comment: You can't implement a check unless you write a small utility that each hour (let's say) download a page from your site to see if it's up. There are sites where you can test rendering results (such as modernie), they'll connect so you'll see if it's reachable. Same with W3C validators. If you're sure it's not a problem with your code I'd ask to your host...

Comment: Seems like a hosting problem..

Comment: `resolve` - routing? application error? **DNS**?

Comment: @EdSF it's not an application error. The browser simply says 'Page cannot be found'. Which, in my opinion, means the host could not be found or the server did not responded.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti the utility you are referring to write... is it not something someone has already built? I mean are there any ready to use solutions?

Comment: Well, yes...even a simple `ping` works pretty well otherwise (to check also server response) a one line PowerShell script like `(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("http://example.com", "temp_file_path")`. Anyway I really think you don't need it, problem **must** be resolved by your service provider.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianoRepetti, you gave me the right direction. I Googled and found a service (siteuptime) where I have scheduled http check on my website and they will send an e-mail if the site is down. The free account supports check every 30 min which is more than enough for me as of now. Once I have some data to prove that site indeed goes down at times, I will contact my service provider for investigation. Thanks again!